# How to move a windows .net runtime frontend application to the cloud (it uses a local sql server backend database)

Tags: sql, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010

I had a engineer design our .net application back in 2009, my guess is that it was coded using visual studio, and all I have is the installer application. We have been using it on our 1 or 2 local client machines very well for the past few years, but now I want to move this front end to the cloud. Instead of installing it as an application on our windows 7 machines.

It is a very simple application used in our small warehouse that keeps track of cargo/shipments etc. It uses Sql Server 2008 Express as a backend which is stored locally.

I know how to get the database in the cloud, their are many options for that, using Amazon or Azure, but how do i get the local client application to the cloud?

I dont have access to the visual studio code, i just have the runtime executable file..

I am sure there is no way to do this, and many of SO users will say i need to re-write the front end.

I have tried to contact the developer and they hav since closed down.  Is their anyway i can run this in the cloud?

I welcome all options and solutions!

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how much this question is on-topic on SO...anyway, did you consider to use **Terminal Server**? It's not exactly _cloud_ but at least you won't need any local installation and it may even be accessed remotely through web (with an ActiveX on IE). Harder part will be to find a good service provider that will let you use TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have two options for hosting this application:

If you are able to configure the database connection string, you could host the database in the cloud, and distribute the application to your end users. However, you've already stated that you know how to move the database, so I assume this isn't an option.

The only alternative is to run the entire application on a cloud server, and send the user interface to a client using terminal services. This makes it appear as if the application is running locally on the user's computer, while it is actually running on the server.

For an off-the-shelf solution to achieve this, you could consider using Microsoft's  [RemoteApp](https://www.remoteapp.windowsazure.com/) Azure service. I'm sure there are other similar offerings available.

Comment: Thanks, Remoteapp seems the way to go, i signed up for it already, and am trying to get it to install my app, but it defaults to excel, word, calc, cannot install my own app.  It seems laggy as everything is remote.  I have decided to re-code everything, well im trying to use a online database creator like caspio, etc... thanks for your help.